# How can I check the "Quick_Check" property of a character (in NFD, say)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

[Unicode Standard Annex #15](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Stable_Code_Points) describes how each character in Unicode, for each of the four normalisation forms, has a "Quick_Check" value that aids in determining whether a given string is in that normalisation form. It goes on to describe, in section 9.1, how this "Quick_Check" value may be used to optimise the concatenation of a string onto a normalised string to produce another normalised string: normalisation need only be performed from the last "stable" character in the left-hand string onwards, where a character is "stable" if it has the "Quick_Check" property and has a canonical combining class of 0. This will generally be more efficient than re-running the normalisation algorithm on the entire concatenated string, if the strings involved are long.

This means that we can concatenate like this: (here the parameter `s1` is assumed to be a string that we know is already in NFD, while `s2` is another string that is not necessarily normalised)

```
def concat (s1, s2):
    LSCP = len(s1) # Last stable character position
    while LSCP > 0:
        LSCP -= 1
        if unicodedata.combining(s1[LSCP]) == 0 and has_nfd_qc(s1[LSCP]):
            break
    return s1[:LSCP] + unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s1[LSCP:] + s2)
```

`unicodedata.combining()` allows us to find out the canonical combining class of a character. But how do we find out whether the character has the "Quick_Check" property for NFD? In other words, what should be substituted for `has_nfd_qc()` in the above?

Answer (score 0):

Like all Unicode data, you can find these properties in the Unicode character database.

> http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/

The quick check properties are in the file `DerivedNormalizationProps.txt`.

> http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/DerivedNormalizationProps.txt

More information about the database can be found in [Unicode Standard Annex #44](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/).

You should also make sure to use the same version of Unicode as `unicodedata.normalize`. Data files for older versions can be found here:

> http://www.unicode.org/Public/

Comment: How do I consult these properties from my Python code?